# How to send in a string into a Gulp task?

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, build-process

**This is step 1** in creating versioned folders for my deployment builds.

How would it be possible to pass in a string into the gulp.task below?

```
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
    runSequence('html-templates',
                'stx-css',
                'app-css',
                'stx-js',
                'app-js',
                'build:copy',
                'build:remove',
                'build:index', cb);
});
```

I'd like to do something like this: `gulp build 1.0.1` which will then pass the string `1.0.1` into the Gulpfile.

```
gulp.task('build', function(version, cb) {
    console.log('version = ', version);
    runSequence('html-templates',
                'stx-css',
                'app-css',
                'stx-js',
                'app-js',
                'build:copy',
                'build:remove',
                'build:index', cb);
});
```

Comment: you mean like using something this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess

Comment: @CookieMonster thanks, but not really... I found a way to accomplish this, going to post it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `env` variable!

**Great video on the subject:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRzCAyNrPV8

So I added this to my Gulpfile:

```
var env = process.env.V; // V={version number}
```

And then added a version task, which calls a function to print out a string that I pass in before calling my build task:

```
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
    runSequence('version',
                'html-templates',
                'stx-css',
                'app-css',
                'stx-js',
                'app-js',
                'build:copy',
                'build:remove',
                'build:index', cb);
});

gulp.task('version', function() {
    return printOut(env);
});

function printOut(version) {
    console.log('version = ',version);
}
```

[image]